# Can .m3u8 playlist files reference OTHER .m3u8 playlist files?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I know that the EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag provides a mechanism for linking to another playlist file, but this appears to be to support variant encoding's (at lower or higher bandwidth) of the same stream. What I would like to do is return a playlist that references actual .ts files but the last reference in the playlist is to the "next" .m3u8.

The reason I want this is that I can use this mechanism to build a stateless HLS server that is not necessarily serving a "live" stream (because the playlist URL can encode information about WHERE in the stream you are). Any idea what players support this (does iOS?)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you describe a scenario in more detail? I'll try to help if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes They can. The main m3u8 that holds other m3u8 is called variant playlist m3u8.
But why we need a variant playlist? - for storing various bit rates of the same stream

I used "One Click m3u8" app from the mac app store - that created the variant playlist as well the children m3u8. No need of ffmpeg or mediafilesegmenter.

[How to video here from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik1VRrACy3s)

[Website](http://www.nacentApps.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in the draft specification (as of draft 10).